# Em PL-SQL como somar parcialmente um valor?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho de somar o valor parcialmente os valores de uma categoria(vai o codigo em abaixo)

```
DECLARE
--VARAVEIS
CURSOR CPRODUTO IS SELECT * FROM PRODUTO_TESTE2;
VPRODUTO PRODUTO_TESTE2%ROWTYPE;
Vsoma real;
BEGIN

Vsoma := 0;

  FOR VPRODUTO IN CPRODUTO LOOP

    /*Valor somente da categoria A*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='A' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 0.5;
     END IF;

    /*Valor somente da categoria B*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='B' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 1.0;
     END IF;

     /*Valor somente da categoria C*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='C' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 2.0;
     END IF; 

     /* Valor Total de todos */
     SELECT sum(VALOR) INTO Vsoma from PRODUTO_TESTE2;

  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Soma Total: ' || Vsoma);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria A: ' || VCatA);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria B: ' || VCatB);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria C: ' || VCatC);
END;
/
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: line 21, column 19: PLS-00201:
>   identifier 'VALOR' must be declared ORA-06550: line 21, column 10:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Deque forma ???

Comment: Categoria s fixas

Comment: estava utilizando VCatA := VALOR;

Comment: Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: line 21, column 19:
PLS-00201: identifier 'VALOR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 21, column 10:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: remove a tag java e inseri sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo entendimento da pergunta é necessário remover o totalizador dentro do laço de repetição.

Realizar alguns ajustes de lógica como:

- Separar o que é regra de negócio em um bloco específico
- A não necessidade de variáveis para cada categoria se a utilização é apenas visual.

Segue o modelo ideal com comentários no código:

```
DECLARE
   --CURSORES
   CURSOR CPRODUTO IS SELECT * FROM PRODUTO_TESTE2;
   --VARIAVEIS
   VPRODUTO PRODUTO_TESTE2%ROWTYPE;
   Vsoma real;
BEGIN

Vsoma := 0;

  -- <REGRA DE NEGÓCIO>
  -- DENTRO LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO NÃO PODE HAVER TOTALIZADORES,
  -- ENQUANTO HOUVER POSSIBILIDADE DE ALTERAÇÃO DE VALORES

  FOR VPRODUTO IN CPRODUTO LOOP

    /*Valor somente da categoria A*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='A' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 0.5;
     END IF;

    /*Valor somente da categoria B*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='B' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 1.0;
     END IF;

     /*Valor somente da categoria C*/ 
     IF VPRODUTO.CATEGORIA='C' THEN
        UPDATE PRODUTO_TESTE2 SET VALOR = VALOR * 2.0;
     END IF;         

  END LOOP;
  -- FINAL DA REGRA DE NEGÓCIO

  -- INICIO DOS TOTALIZADORES

  /* Valor Total de todos */
  SELECT sum(VALOR) INTO Vsoma from PRODUTO_TESTE2;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Soma Total: ' || Vsoma);

  /*Valor somente da categoria A*/ 
  SELECT sum(VALOR) INTO Vsoma from PRODUTO_TESTE2 WHERE CATEGORIA = 'A'; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria A: ' || Vsoma);

  /*Valor somente da categoria B*/ 
  SELECT sum(VALOR) INTO Vsoma from PRODUTO_TESTE2 WHERE CATEGORIA = 'B';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria B: ' || Vsoma);

  /*Valor somente da categoria C*/ 
  SELECT sum(VALOR) INTO Vsoma from PRODUTO_TESTE2 WHERE CATEGORIA = 'C';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Categoria C: ' || Vsoma);

END;
```

Só não entendi a utilização dos `UPDATES` sem `WHERE`...

[OFF TOPIC]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQCbJ.jpg

Comment: Correto, inserir as WHERE em cada linha